# Homepage was not listing given category products

Tags: magento-1.9, category, catalog

I have added the design code as like this in homepage.

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="548"  template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
</block>
</reference>
```

but the particular category-id related products are not displaying... but displaying all the category products..

how to make it to display the particular category id related products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code..

```
 <reference name="content">
              <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
              <action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>548</category_id></action>
                            </block>
    </reference>
```

Comment: Its working.. but Recommended Products are showing different..

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: Its working.. but Recommended Products are showing different.  Please check this link www.77hydro.com

Comment: it may be  include the subcategories products

Comment: this is the actual 548 category id page http://77hydro.com/nutrients-supplements.html .. here its displaying properly...

Comment: you want toolbar too?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30485/discussion-between-d-m-vamsi-and-qaisar-satti).